# How many "minimal sequences" are there?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, graph-theory

A coin is tossed repeatedly and the outcome is recorded as a sequence of H's and T's.  We are interested in obtaining every possible n-bit string as contiguous subsequences of our coin tossing sequence in a minimum number of coin tosses. The subsequences are allowed to overlap.  We want to know how many different minimal sequences there are.

For example, If n=1 then there are 2 such sequences: TH and HT.

For n=2 we want to obtain all four of the  2-bit subsequences TT, TH, HT, HH.
There are 4 such sequences TTHHT, THHTT, HHTTH HTTHH.

Fro n=3 there are 16 such sequences: {T, T, T, H, H, H, T, H, T, T}, {T, T, H, H, H, T, H, T, T, T}, {T, H, H, H, T, H, T, T, T, T}, {H, H, H, T, H, T, T, T, T, T},
 {H, H, T,H, T, T, T, T, T, H}, {H, T, H, T, T, T, T, T, H, H}, {T, H, T, T, T, T, T, H, H, H}, {H, T, T, T, T, T, H, H, H, T}, {T, T, T, H, T, H, H, H, T, T, T}, {T, T, H, T, H, H, H, T, T, T, T}, {T, H, T, H, H, H, T, T, T, T, T}, {H, T, H, H, H, T, T, T, T, T, T}, {T, H, H, H, T, T, T, T, T, T, H}, {H, H, H, T, T, T, T, T, T, H, T},
{H, H, T, T, T, T, T, T, H, T, H}, {H, T, T, T, T, T, T, H, T, H, H}.

According to Eric Weisstein's Math World article "Coin Tossing" the number of such sequences is 2^2^(n-1).  I do not understand why this is true.
The problem might be reduced to a graph theory problem: see the Wikipedia article "DeBruijn Sequences".

Comment: Do you understand why you want a DeBruijn sequence? There are $2^{2^{n-1}-n}$ of them.

Comment: OK, I think I have this now. Would you agree that the number of Eulerian circuits in an    (n - 1) dimensional DeBruijn graph is equal to the number of minimal sequences containing every possible n-bit sequence?  I see there must be 2^2^(n-1) of these.